# Python using index to check in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, compare

I am working on a script where the goal is to check each country (`country`) and based on the index if the entry exist in the `supply` list. The goal is to print out for each country which entry does exist and not.

Country:

```
country=['usa', 'poland', 'australia', 'china']
```

The index used to check for each of the items in `country` towards `supply`.

```
# index
water_country=water_<country>_country
gas_state=gas_<country>_state
oil_city=oil_<country>_city
```

Supply:

```
supply=['water_usa_country', 'gas_usa_state', 'oil_usa_city', 'water_poland_country', 'gas_poland_city', 'gas_australia_state']
```

For the case above the result is to be in a list for each country:

```
For country 'usa' all entries exist

For country 'poland' following entries does not exist:
oil_poland_city

For country 'australia' following entries does not exist:
water_australia_country
oil_australia _city   

For country 'china' following entries does not exist:
water_china_country
gas_china_state
oil_china_city
```

Comment: Why store such information as strings in the first place? This looks like a job for `dicts`, named tuples or even classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
countries = ['usa', 'poland', 'australia', 'china']
search_strings = ['water_{}_country', 'gas_{}_state', 'oil_{}_city']
supply = ['water_usa_country', 'gas_usa_state', 'oil_usa_city', 'water_poland_country', 'gas_poland_city', 'gas_australia_state']

for country in countries:
    missing = [search_string.format(country) for search_string in search_strings if search_string.format(country) not in supply]
    if missing:
        missing_string = '\n'.join(missing)
        print(f"For country '{country}' the following entries do not exist:\n{missing_string}\n")

    else:
        print(f"For country '{country}' all entries exist.\n")
```

Output:

```
For country 'usa' all entries exist.

For country 'poland' the following entries do not exist:
gas_poland_state
oil_poland_city

For country 'australia' the following entries do not exist:
water_australia_country
oil_australia_city

For country 'china' the following entries do not exist:
water_china_country
gas_china_state
oil_china_city
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over all of your supplies for each country and check which supplies are met, and add those that are not to some list, here values of `missing_supplies`.

```
country = ['usa', 'poland', 'australia', 'china']
index = ['water_<country>_country', 'gas_<country>_state', 'oil_<country>_city']
supply = ['water_usa_country', 'gas_usa_state', 'oil_usa_city', 'water_poland_country', 'gas_poland_city', 'gas_australia_state']

missing_supplies = {}

for c in country:
    missing_supplies[c] = []
    for i in index:
        if i.replace('<country>', c) not in supply:
            missing_supplies[c].append(i.replace('<country>', c))

for c in country:
    if not missing_supplies[c]:
        print('For country \'{}\' all entries exist'.format(c))
    else:
        print('For country \'{}\' following entries does not exist:'.format(c))
        for v in missing_supplies[c]:
            print(v)
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
For country 'usa' all entries exist

For country 'poland' following entries does not exist:
gas_poland_state
oil_poland_city

For country 'australia' following entries does not exist:
water_australia_country
oil_australia_city

For country 'china' following entries does not exist:
water_china_country
gas_china_state
oil_china_city
```